# Regex on Camel-Rest component

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Camel-Rest with Netty4-Http component and trying to consume all incoming messages with a specific prefix. i.e: my problem is when defining: rest("/api/user") and calling "http://host:port/api/user/someMorePath" it will not be consumed by the Camel-Rest, only when I'll call the specific path: "http://host:port/api/user".
I know Netty4-Http enables to do so with the option "?matchOnUriPrefix=true" but couldn't make it to work with Camel-Rest.
Any ideas?
Thx.

Comment: Yeah I wonder if we can go a bit off spec and maybe support a wildcard notation, so you can declare in the rest-dsl, rest("/api/user/*") to have it accept sub paths as well.

Comment: I logged a ticket - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8306